# Regular Expression validation in ASP.NET for special chars

Tags: asp.net, .net, regex, validation

I need to validate the scenario in Regex, I'm using RegularExpression validation in ASP.NET.

1. Shouldn't start or end with SPACE
2. Doesn't contain only SPACE
3. whole string shouldn't contain two special char "@" & "?"

Valid:

```
"as#d qwe2", "&^%$$(&+_", "12#$.p"
```

InValid:

```
"  ", "asd ", " asd#", "ksdhf?kh", "asdf@asd"
```

I'm trying with this:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox1"
        ErrorMessage="RegularExpressionValidator" 
        ValidationExpression="^[^\s]+(\s+[^@?]+)*[^\s]$">Error</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: tried with "^[^\s]+(\s+[^@?]+)*[^\s]$", not working...

Answer (score 0):

Untested RegEx: `^([^ @?][^@?]*[^ @?]|[^ @?])$`

Comment: What kind of Regex engine are you using? .NET's `Regex.IsMatch ("   ", @"^[^ ][^@?]*[^ ]$")` returns `false`.

Comment: This allows a string to start/end with [@?], and it disallows single-character strings.

Comment: Good catch - improved.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems with the regex you are currently using:

1. `^[^\s]+` is matching almost all of the string if it does not start with a space character (thus matching `@` or `?`).
2. Due to the way the regex is constructed, you can only input strings of length 2 and above. This is a minor setback, but can be avoided.

I would suggest using negative lookaheads since there are multiple 'checks' to do on the first character:

```
^(?!\s|.*\s$)[^?@]+$
```

`(?!\s|.*\s$)` will prevent a match if the string begins with `\s` or ends with `\s` and `[^?@]+` matches all characters but `?` and `@`. Space only strings will automatically be rejected because space only strings will have to begin with a space.

Comment: if i provide only spaces then the aspx page is getting post back, ideally it shouldn't...
have u tested it?

Comment: @user3398663 I don't have aspx to implement the code you have in your question, but I have tested it in regex tools that use C#/ASP.NET based regex engine and the above does not match space only strings.

Comment: @user3398663 Maybe you could try using actual spaces " " rather than `\s`? Just an idea.

Comment: @user3398663 I found an online IDE, and it appears to be working [fine](http://ideone.com/TGOwVe) in C#. Are other strings that begin and/or end with space also getting posted back?

Comment: the following strings are working fine: " a ", " a", "a ".....   but only spaces not working.

Comment: @user3398663 Ok. Just for testing purposes, what happens if you use `^[^\s]+$` for regex and insert space-only text? Ideally, it should not get posted back with that regex, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82691/discussion-between-user3398663-and-jerry).